# How to find the maximum overlap between columns of the same rows of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Given two dataframes, how would you find the maximum overlap of start and end values, between rows, and pair them based on the overlap in a new dataframe, and also rank the other overlaps by decreasing overlap?

```
df_1
  start      end
a     1       10
b    20       50
c    70      100


df_2
  start     end
a     5      10
b    70     120
c    20      30
```

In this case row a of df_1 is paired with row a of df_2, since they share the greatest overlap. Row b of df_1 is paired with row c of df_2, since they also share the greatest overlap, and so on.

So the resulting df_3 dataframe would be:

```
df_1    df_2
a       a
b       c
c       b
```

After this, how would you then rank the rest of the possible overlaps for each row in descending order, and also in the case of too many possibilities, only rank n greatest overlaps in order.

Answer (score 1):

Try with range index and `overlap`

```
idx1 = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(
                              df1['start'], 
                              df1['end'], 
                              closed='both')
df2['new'] = df2.apply(lambda x : df1.index[idx1.overlaps(pd.Interval(x['start'], x['end'], closed='both'))][0],axis=1)
df2
   start  end new
a      5   10   a
b     70  120   c
c     20   30   b
```