# Remove rows from dataframe if it has partial match with other rows for specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to remove rows in a dataframe which have partial overlaps in their start and end character indices.

Details:

I have two sentences and I have extracted some entities from them and organized them in a dataframe.

sentences :

```
| id  |            sentence                          |
| --- |             ---                              |
|  1  | Today is a very sunny day and sun is shining |
|  2  | I bought the red balloon and playing with it |
```

My dataframe with the extracted entities looks like this:

```
| id |     data        | start_char_index | end_char index | token_position |
| ---| --------------  | ---------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1  | very sunny day  |      11          |      26        |  [4,5,6]       |
| 1  | shining         |      37          |      45        |    [10]        |
| 1  | sunny           |      16          |      21        |    [5]         |
| 2  | the red balloon |      9           |      25        |   [3,4,5]      | 
| 2  | playing         |      29          |      37        |     [7]        |
| 2  | red             |      13          |      16        |     [4]        |
```

P.S. In this token position is the index of the specific token in text (starting from 1)

Now, for id 1. we see that 'very sunny day' and 'sunny' are partial overlaps (their start and end character indices and token position both overlap)
Same for id 2, where 'the red balloon' and 'red' have red which is an overlap and I want to remove the rows 'sunny' and 'red' which are smaller of the overlaps in the two different ids.

I thought about grouping them on ids and then removing those records by storing the start and end character indices (or token position) in  a dictionary, but if I have alot of data rows and lot of ids, then it would be very slow.
Also I read about IntervalTree but I could not get to use it for partial overlaps very efficiently.

So could you please suggest some solution for this?

The final output dataframe should look like this:

```
| id |     data        | start_char_index | end_char index | token_position |
| ---| --------------  | ---------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1  | very sunny day  |      11          |      26        |  [4,5,6]       |
| 1  | shining         |      37          |      45        |    [10]        |
| 2  | the red balloon |      9           |      25        |   [3,4,5]      | 
| 2  | playing         |      29          |      37        |     [7]        |
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: How has `balloon` and `sunny` same position?

Comment: I think the id refers to the string the data came from, so sunny is position 5 of string 1 and balloon is position 5 of string 2

Comment: Yes, as Patrick points, token_position indicates the index of token in the respective sentences indicated by the id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Mortz's answer, I also tried pandas IntervalArray and overlap  which was working faster for me. Putting it here for anyone else who might find it useful (Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69336914/15941713 ):

```
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree
def drop_subspan_duplicates(df):

   idx1 = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(
                          df['start'], 
                          df['end'], 
                          closed='both')

  df['wrd_id'] = df.apply(lambda x : df.index[idx1.overlaps(pd.Interval(x['start'], x['end'], closed='both'))][0],axis=1)
  df= df.drop_duplicates(['wrd_id'],keep='first')
  df.drop(['wrd_id'],axis=1,inplace=True)
  return df

output = data.groupby('id').apply(drop_subspan_duplicates)
```

One can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425881/15941713) answer for tackling the issue if one wishes to avoid dataframe operations

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure a `DataFrame` is the best structure to solve this problem - but here is one approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1], 'start': [11, 20, 16], 'end': [18, 35, 17]})

# First we construct a range of numbers from the start and end index
df.loc[:, 'range'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(range(x['start'], x['end'])), axis=1)

# Next, we "cumulate" these ranges and measure the number of unique elements in the cumulative range at each row 
df['range_size'] = df['range'].cumsum().apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))

# Finally we check if every row adds anything to the cumulative range - if a new row adds nothing, then we can drop that row
df['range_size_shifted'] = df['range'].cumsum().apply(lambda x: len(set(x))).shift(1)
df['drop'] = df.apply(lambda x: False if pd.isna(x['range_size_shifted']) else not int(x['range_size'] - x['range_size_shifted']), axis=1)

print(df)
#   id  start  end   drop
#0   1     11   18  False
#1   1     20   35  False
#2   1     16   17   True
```

If you want to do this for each group separately -

```
for key, group in df.groupby('id'):
    group.loc[:, 'range'] = group.apply(lambda x: list(range(x['start'], x['end'])), axis=1)
    group['range_size'] = group['range'].cumsum().apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
    group['range_size_shifted'] = group['range'].cumsum().apply(lambda x: len(set(x))).shift(1)
    group['drop'] = group.apply(lambda x: False if pd.isna(x['range_size_shifted']) else not int(x['range_size'] - x['range_size_shifted']), axis=1)
    print(group)
```

Comment: While this solves the problem for me, but it is not very efficient on big data sizes. Is there a way to optimize this solution?

Comment: You'd need to provide more context to the problem - where are you reading the data from? How big is the data? Do you **have** to use pandas and dataframes? Compared to what alternative is this solution sub-optimal?

Comment: The data size is in millions in form of a dataframe itself, so I have to use pandas and dataframe. 
I used intervaltree overlaps function, and for the same data, the intervaltree function was faster than the solution here. 
Please note, that by optimized and sub optimal, I am just compared the processing speed on the data